# MySql UPDATE weird behavior

Tags: php, mysql

It's probably a stupid mistake on my side, I know.

I was trying to add a suffix to all post titles and a specific tag to all my posts in my blog (blog is a custom coded project for learning purposes). Once that wasn't working, I tried to update it manually using phpMyAdmin, but with no success.

So, why is this not working:

```
UPDATE
    posts
SET
    title = 'myNewTitle',
    tags  = 'myStupidTag'
WHERE
    id = 1
```

All I'm getting is OK status from mysql, but with 0 rows affected. However, if I use same ID in `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT`, I get post data just fine.

Is smt wrong with my query?

And here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `html` text,
  `tags` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=80 ;
```

Comment: show us the `UPDATE ... SELECT` as well

Comment: If there's 0 row affected after update it means there is no data to be updated, i.e. title and tag values are already set to myNewTitle and myStupidTag

Comment: Following on from the previous comments, have your tried SELECTing the row with ID 1 before and after the UPDATE?  As Mchl says, an UPDATE will return OK if the UPDATE syntax is correct, and 0 rows if no rows were changed.  Perhaps you could try using different values for your columns...

Comment: Ok... this is even more strange... I tried it again, and it worked. However, I'm still getting msg: 0 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.0015 sec ), and I see in the db that row HAS ACTUALLY changed. Does UPDATE query doesn't count modified rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really sure that PHPMyAdmin says OK to your `UPDATE` query although there are no rows affected?

Your `WHERE` clause is wrong - the `ID` field has to be uppercase - not lowercase!

Try instead:

```
UPDATE posts
SET title = 'myNewTitle',
    tags = 'myStupidTag'
WHERE ID = 1
```

kind regards

**EDIT**:

wrong - user ajreal already corrected me!

But: your query must work - I tried it with your table scheme and some random generated data...

Comment: case insensitive on column, case sensitive on table ...so, it does not matters

Comment: Well, I just realized that it seems to be working. I commented in my question comments. No idea what's going on. When trying things manually, I'm using mysql root user, and he has all the privileges. I even managed to delete one table by accident yesterday :)

Answer (score -1):

mysql  case insensitivity on column windows and unix,try

```
    select * from posts where ID=1
```

to check your posts table have data

Comment: If it was a case sensitivity problem, mysql would complain `Unknown column 'id' ...` or whatever, not say "0 rows updated"